# Host files on AWS S3 that can be downloaded from specific website but not from elsewhere

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a website where users can upload resources (e.g. pdf-files) to their account. I am using AWS S3 to host all the uploaded files, and I am using the AWS Java SDK 1.8.9.1 for communications between my website and S3.

Now, I want to allow users to be able to download and view the files that they have uploaded, but I only want this to be possible through my website. That is, on my web site, users should have a download link for each of their files that they can click, after which the download starts. However, if they copy the URL of the download link and send it to their friend, that friend should not be able to download the file.

I know that it is possible to restrict access to S3 buckets to specified referring URLs. However, I have also been told that this can easily be forged and is not the way to go. I am thinking that there might exist a solution with signed requests.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your application so that the download links are proxied through it. i.e. The application should do the reverse of the upload process.

So, you can provide a link to your java application, which will then go to S3 and retrieve the file and return it to the user. This way, if someone shares a link, you can protect the url and require users to login before they can download the file.

Comment: But won't this add a lot of work to my server, meaning that the entire point of hosting files on S3 is missed?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'work'. Yes, it will add a lot to your network traffic, but not to your CPU load. Unfortunately, there's not a lot else you can do. You could lock down folders in S3 using IAM credentials, but then you'd need to provide IAM credentials to all of your users.

Comment: Also, I'd say that the primary features of S3 are high availability and reliability. You still get those.

Comment: Hmm, I'm a bit surprised that this is the only option. Anyway, I'll accept your answer if nothing better comes up. :-)

Comment: :) I wouldn't say it was the only option. But I don't think there is too much more you can do. You need a way of authenticating the requests, S3 does provide some facilities to do this, but if you want to integrate with your authentication system, then the requests really have to go through your server.